# Diff hash table return value

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I'm doing a Compare-Object where my ref object is a list of strings and the diff object is a hash table

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $localmd5 -DifferenceObject $remotefilehash | Where-Object { ($_.SideIndicator -eq '=>')}
```

The side-indicator gets me all the ones that I'm interested in but what I want is the value from the hash-table returned - how can I do this?

**UPDATE 1**:

The ask -  I need to compare the localmd5 to the hashtable KEYS and return the VALUES

Comment: So, are you saying that you want all the "actual" unique values returned?

Comment: yes - something like ```| select-object $remotefilehash.values``` but only the ones that get passed from the where step

Comment: Do you want to compare the values stored in HashTable with the strings stored in the other list (Ref object) ?

Comment: yes thats what the Compare-Object pipe is doing

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just convert your HashTable values to a String Array and then compare them both?

1. Convert your values stored in HashTable to a String array:

   `$hashTableValues = $remotefilehash.Values.ForEach('ToString')`
2. Then, simply compare both the String arrays (`$localmd5` and `$hashTableValues`) and get your unique values using `Select-Object` cmdlet:

   `Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $localmd5 -DifferenceObject $hashTableValues | Where-Object { ($_.SideIndicator -eq '=>')} | Select-Object InputObject`

**As per your updated question:**

You can fetch the keys you're interested in by doing something like this:

```
$requiredKeys = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $localmd5 -DifferenceObject ($remotefilehash.Keys.GetEnumerator() -join ',').Split(' ') | Where-Object { ($_.SideIndicator -eq '=>')} | Select-Object InputObject
```

Then, you can convert these keys to an array of strings:

```
$keysAsString = $requiredKeys | Foreach {"$($_.InputObject)"}
```

Now, since you've got the list of keys for which you want the values, you can use these keys as indexes and fetch the required values from HashTable:

```
foreach($key in $keysAsString)
{
    foreach($hKey in $remotefilehash.Keys)
    {
        if($hKey.ToString() -eq $key)
        {
            Write-Output $hash[$hKey] #use the value accordingly
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry b/c I need to compare the localmd5 to the hashtable KEYS and return the VALUES

Comment: this doesn't seeem to get me the values only the keys...

Comment: I mentioned earlier that you can use the keys as indexes to fetch the values from HashTable, but since you were still confused, I added the code to do that as well (made some minor changes to existing code as well, so please take note of that before trying out the solution).

Comment: @Tony - Please mark the answer as Accepted in case it helped you fix your problem. Thanks!